# Validate null columns values in a select statement in BigQuery

Tags: validation, google-bigquery

I'm trying to make a select to a bigquery table, but I need to assign a default value to a column if it is null, because next in the process I need the default or the real item_id value, I was trying to use the CASE validation but I'm not pretty sure if I can use this clause for this purpose, and I'm getting the next error:

```
Expected end of input but got keyword case.

Select
p.item_id CASE WHEN item_id IS NULL THEN 'XXXXX' ELSE item_id END AS item_id,
from items
where -- rest of the query
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Select
IFNULL(p.item_id,'XXXXX') AS item_id,
from items
where -- rest of the query
```

**`IFNULL()` function in BigQuery**

```
IFNULL(expr, null_result)
```

**Description**

If expr is NULL, return null_result. Otherwise, return expr. If expr is not NULL, null_result is not evaluated.

expr and null_result can be any type and must be implicitly coercible to a common supertype. Synonym for COALESCE(expr, null_result).

more details: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#ifnull

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
isnull(yourcolumn,'') 
--or
isnull(yourcolumn,99999999)
```

and you can put anything between those quotes. If the value is an int that won't work though. You will need to make it some default number, preferably something that would never be used like 9999999999.